# Retag and make [github-for-windows] a synonym of [github-desktop]

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

It seems that [github-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-for-windows) gained support for macOS, and was renamed [github-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-desktop), but we ended up with a new tag rather than renaming the old one.

Can we synonymize the former to the latter?